# Installation issue of CUDA and cuDNN on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, nvidia, cudnn

I am checking the CUDA and cuDNN installation on a system, and have several observations:

1. CUDA has two versions, 9.0 and 11.2
2. cuDNN was only found in the installation directory of CUDA 9.0
3. In the directory of CUDA 9.0, it has cudafe.exe while the directory of CUDA 11.2 does not have

In accordance with the current scenario, do I have to uninstall one of CUDA versions to avoid conflict?

[image]

Comment: no you should not have to.  Multiple CUDA versions can live side-by-side, and the same is true for CUDNN.   You'll need to make sure that any projects are set up appropriately to use the versions you desire.  You can only have one GPU driver installed in a machine at a time, and generally recommend to use the latest driver for your GPU. This driver will support multiple CUDA versions (e.g. 9.0, and 11.2).

Answer (score 3):

You can have both versions together. However, you can only use one of them a time. For cuDNN, you will need to download it from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) for CUDA 11.2, and put the files in "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2". Finally, make sure you set the system path to the desired version. For example, if you want CUDA 11.2, then open "Environment Variables", and make sure that both "CUDA_PATH" and "CUDNN" are "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2". Also it must inside the variable "Path".
[image]
[image]